# Displaying more than just text in a ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a UI for managing teams which are composed of a name and two colors (among other things).  I'd like for the ListView (on the left) to display the name, a swatch of the primary color, and a swatch of the secondary color for each line.  I'm very new at WPF and databinding, and I'm not really sure where to start.

**Current:**

[image: current]

**Goal:**

[image: Goal]

**Relevant code:**

**Team.cs**

```
public class Team : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private Color _color;
    private Color _secondaryColor;

    public string name { ... }
    public Color color { ... }
    public Color secondaryColor { ... }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Team(string name, Color color, Color secondaryColor)
    {
        _name = name;
        _color = color;
        _secondaryColor = secondaryColor;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) { ... }
}
```

**SettingsWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public SettingsWindow()
{
    teams = TeamManager.Instance().teamList;
    this.DataContext = this.teams;
    if (!Application.Current.Resources.Contains("selectedTeam"))
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("selectedTeam", selectedTeam);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**SettingsWindow.xaml**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMemberPath="name"
          SelectionChanged="ListTeamSelected" SelectionMode="Single">

    <!-- I'm guessing it'll go somewhere in the ItemContainerStyle,
         but I'm not sure if that's correct or how to do it -->

    <!--<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding color}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>-->
</ListView>
```

**TeamManager.cs**

```
public class TeamList : ObservableCollection<Team>
{
    public TeamList() : base() { }
}
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
      SelectionChanged="ListTeamSelected" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding color, Converter="{StaticResource colorFixer}}" Width="25" Margin="5"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="{Binding secondaryColor, Converter="{StaticResource colorFixer}}" Width="25" Margin="5"/>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

but you can't use Color as Fill (or Background for a Border) you have to convert it to a Brush first. in order to do so you can create a converter as follows:

```
public class ColorFixer : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush((Color)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

finally add it to your xaml's resources:

```
<conv:ColorFixer x:Key="colorFixer"/>
```

make sure you have included the namespace for the converter class:

```
<Window    
     ...
     xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

### Edit

you can avoid using a converter and simply use the following code instead:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
      SelectionChanged="ListTeamSelected" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Margin="5"/>
                <Rectangle Width="25" Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding color}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Rectangle Width="25" Margin="5">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding secondaryColor}"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into the [`ItemTemplate` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can specify a `DataTemplate` and write xaml within here to specify the layout. You can then do something like this, as the `DataContext` for each `ListViewItem` will map to what you specify as the `ItemSource`.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
           <TextBlock Name="{Binding name}"/>
           <Rectangle Fill="{Binding color}"/>
           <!-- etc -->
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Edit: Note the removal of the `DisplayMemberPath` property.